# C# How to detect if camera is focused on road or windshield

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, camera, autofocus

**What I'm trying to do:**

I need to focus my android phone camera on the road so that it can serve as a dash cam.

**The problem:**

Sometimes the auto focus, focuses the camera on the grime or raindrops of the windshield instead of the road.

First solution was to try and force the focus of the camera to a distance, but it seems that on a regular android phone. That is not possible with any of the Auto Focus methods.
Also `GetFocusDistances()` returns infinity for the far, middle, and near floats.

My second idea is to calculate the blurriness of the camera to determine if its focused close or far.

Using this OpenCV method:

```
    static double Variance(Mat image)
    {
        using (var laplacian = new Mat())
        {
            int kernel_size = 3;
            int scale = 1;
            int delta = 0;
            int ddepth = image.Type().Depth;
            Cv2.Laplacian(image, laplacian, ddepth, kernel_size, scale, delta);
            Cv2.MeanStdDev(laplacian, out var mean, out var stddev);
            return stddev.Val0 * stddev.Val0;
        }
    }
```

It returns the value `2881.0` for the clear image and `267.0` for the blurry image which could work.

However, when I tested it on a second image using a glass cup and a worse camera:

It returned `405.0` for the blurry image and `546.0` for the clear image which is too narrow of a difference to use reliably.

How can I determine if the camera is in close focus or far focus programmatically so that I can have the android camera auto focus in a loop until its at the far distance I need?

Edit: Still looking for suggestions

Comment: How about disabling autofocus and set it to inifinity? This will always give you what you want since the objects are always going to be far away.

Comment: @Cheesebaron setting it to infinity makes everything look blurry except the sky I assume. Its suppose to be used for very far away landscapes or sky shots.

Comment: Depends on the focal length. It is quite small on phones. If you keep telling the camera to auto focus, chances are that you get the same blurry picture over and over again.

Comment: @Cheesebaron It only happens when there is something in the way for it to focus, such as rain drops.